# Is it possible to check self-signed certificates with google apps script UrlFetchApp

Tags: ssl, google-apps-script

I want to use UrlFetchApp to connect to a (yet to deploy) server, and validateHttpCerts to 'true'. Can this be done with GAS?

The servers will have use self-signed certificates.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the "This Application was Created by Another User, not By Google" message?

Comment: I was in the wrong understanding of self-signed certificates.

UrlFetchApp can validateHttpsCerts: false, so that works.